# How to Calculate the PUSH AX?

Tags: computer-science

The stack segment register has been loaded with 0000 and stack pointer
register with 4000H. If register AX contains 1244H, what is the result of PUSH AX?

Comment: Why are you asking us to do your homework?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.